# How to send value input type text via ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have input type text like this

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
```

And i have ajax post function like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 300,                 // set editor height
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true,                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(files) {
                sendFile(files[0]);
            }
        }
    });   

    function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
        document.getElementById("loading_upload_threads_image").style.display = "block";
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", file);//You can append as many data as you want. Check mozilla docs for this
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "threads_image_upload.php",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(url) {
                $('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
                document.getElementById("loading_upload_threads_image").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to know how to send value from `id="test"`to my ajax post ?

Comment: It should already be in your form data, but make sure you use the form with the `formData()` call: `new formData($('form')[0])`. Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard OP creates an empty `FormData` object

Comment: Ack! Good catch @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Please also do `$("#loading_upload_threads_image").hide()` /  `.show()`

Comment: @mplungjan before `$("#loading_upload_threads_image").show()` i want to delay for 3 sec how can i do ?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { $("#loading_upload_threads_image").show()},3000);`

Comment: delay it's work good, please see my code but why `#loading_upload_threads_image` still hide before show content from `$('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `append()` method to add any data you want to the `FormData` object - as your comment event says. Try this:

```
data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);
data.append('test', $('#test').val());
```

Alternatively, if you want to send all the data in your form then you can provide the `form` element to the `FormData` constructor. Note that the items will be given the name of the `input` as the key.

```
var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

Comment: and how to use value `id="test"` in threads_image_upload.php ?

Comment: Well you're sending a POST request, so `$_POST["test"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="">
```

JS Code:

```js
data = new FormData();
data.append("file", file);
data.append("test", $('#test').val());

$.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    url: "threads_image_upload.php",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(url) {
        $('#summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
        document.getElementById("loading_upload_threads_image").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

and in PHP you can access it as:

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and how to use value `id="test"` in threads_image_upload.php ?

Comment: As according to raw php, you can access it as: `$_POST['test']`